# Ruby, how to reduce an array of dates in string format keeping only month and array index

Tags: ruby

I need to draw a chart and on the X axis I have dates...
I have an array like this...

```
data = ["2020-02-15",
 "2020-02-16",
 "2020-02-17",
 "2020-02-18",
 "2020-02-19",
 "2020-02-20",
 "2020-02-21",
 "2020-02-22",
 "2020-02-23",
 "2020-02-24",
 "2020-02-25",
 "2020-02-26",
 "2020-02-27",
 "2020-02-28",
 "2020-02-29" ... ]
```

The array has about 500 elements...
I cannot draw 500 labels, I just need the month.

My label has this format

```
g.labels = {0 => '2003', 2 => '2004', 4 => '2005', 6 => '2006'}
```

The key is the index, the value is the month.

So I use

```
x = Hash[(0...data.size).zip data]
```

And the result is

```
{0=>"2020-02-15",
 1=>"2020-02-16",
 2=>"2020-02-17",
 3=>"2020-02-18",
 4=>"2020-02-19",
 5=>"2020-02-20"}
```

Now I have to keep just the month. Because the first value is "2020-02-15" I start with february 15th, then I have to keep march 15th, etc...

The result must be

```
{0=>"February",
 30=>"March",
 61=>"April"...}
```

How can I do?

Comment: Do you want to keep same month again and again like `{0 => "2", 1 => "2"}` or you want the month to be unique like `{0 => "2", 1 => "3"}` ?

Comment: What's your expected result? And ... can you give an example that contains other months as well?

Comment: @ZainArshad I just need one month

Comment: @RobertoPezzali where do `0`, `30`, and `61` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work with regexp or just use the Date class:

```
[8] pry(main)> h
=> {0=>"2020-02-15", 1=>"2020-02-16", 2=>"2020-02-17", 3=>"2020-02-18", 4=>"2020-02-19", 5=>"2020-02-20"}
[10] pry(main)> h.each do |k,v|
[10] pry(main)*   puts "date #{k} month number is #{Date.parse(v).month}"
[10] pry(main)* end
date 0 month number is 2
date 1 month number is 2
date 2 month number is 2
date 3 month number is 2
date 4 month number is 2
date 5 month number is 2
```

or by name:

```
[11] pry(main)> h.each do |k,v|
[11] pry(main)*   puts "date #{k} month number is #{Date.parse(v).strftime("%B")}"
[11] pry(main)* end
date 0 month number is February
date 1 month number is February
date 2 month number is February
date 3 month number is February
date 4 month number is February
date 5 month number is February
```

Since you want to use array tou do not need to use has notation:

```
[18] pry(main)> h.values
=> ["2020-02-15", "2020-02-16", "2020-02-17", "2020-02-18", "2020-02-19", "2020-02-20"]
[19] pry(main)> h.values.map { |d| Date.parse(d).month }
=> [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2]
```

or you can map over a hash and modify the hash itself:

```
[20] pry(main)> h
=> {0=>"2020-02-15", 1=>"2020-02-16", 2=>"2020-02-17", 3=>"2020-02-18", 4=>"2020-02-19", 5=>"2020-02-20"}
[21] pry(main)> h.update(h){ |_,d| Date.parse(d).month }
=> {0=>2, 1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>2, 4=>2, 5=>2}
[22] pry(main)> h
=> {0=>2, 1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>2, 4=>2, 5=>2}

[24] pry(main)> h.transform_values! { |v| Date.parse(v).month }
=> {0=>2, 1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>2, 4=>2, 5=>2}
```

but I recoomend to create a new hash

```
[26] pry(main)> h.transform_values { |v| Date.parse(v).month }
=> {0=>2, 1=>2, 2=>2, 3=>2, 4=>2, 5=>2}
[27] pry(main)> h
=> {0=>"2020-02-15", 1=>"2020-02-16", 2=>"2020-02-17", 3=>"2020-02-18", 4=>"2020-02-19", 5=>"2020-02-20"}
```

finally for your result:

```
[28] pry(main)> h.transform_values { |v| Date.parse(v).strftime("%B") }
=> {0=>"February", 1=>"February", 2=>"February", 3=>"February", 4=>"February", 5=>"February"}
```

you can also filter values on a hash:

```
[29] pry(main)> h.select { |k,v| Date.parse(v).day == 15 }.transform_values { |v| Date.parse(v).strftime("%B") }
=> {0=>"February"}
```

Comment: I added the result i need

Comment: Finally I get it, the last edit is your result, hope this helps!!

Comment: Is not what I need exacty. I need to filter my has to extract only the values where the day is the "15", so the middle of the month... and then use  h.transform_values { |v| Date.parse(v).strftime("%B") }

Comment: l.select {|k,v| Date.parse(v).strftime("%d").to_i == 15 }

Comment: I added all the things to the answer please consider to upvote

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
data = {0=>"2020-02-15",
    1=>"2020-02-16",
    2=>"2020-03-17",
    3=>"2020-04-18",
    4=>"2020-05-19",
    5=>"2020-09-20",
    6=>"2020-04-15",
    7=>"2020-04-20",
    8=>"2020-06-15",
    9=>"2020-09-15"}
match_date = Date.parse(data.first.last).day
months = data.map{|k, v| [k, Date.parse(v).strftime("%B")] if Date.parse(v).day == match_date}.compact.to_h
```

**Output:**

```
{0=>"February", 6=>"April", 8=>"June", 9=>"September"}
```